# Attribute error in python classes in tkinter library

Tags: python, tkinter

```
from tkinter import *
gui = Tk()
gui.geometry("500x500")
gui.configure(bg='orange')
class main:
    def __init__(self,master):
        self.master=master
        self.frame1= Frame(self.master,bg='orange')
        self.frame1.pack(side=TOP)
        self.metho()
    def metho(event,self):
        self.bnt1 = Button(self.frame1,bg='orange',text='print',height=2,width=7)
        self.bnt1.grid(row=0,column=1)
        self.bnt1.bind("<Enter>",self.ty)

    def ty(self):
        print("hello")

i = main(gui)
gui.mainloop()
```

This is the error:

```
TypeError: metho() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

Hey! I am trying to bind my button and I am getting an error. Please help me how to resolve this error. I will be thankful to you.

Answer (score 1):

Considering that the `metho` method is creating the button and the `ty` method is the callback you are binding it to:

1. Remove the 'event' parameter from `metho`, as the tkinter `event` is not sent to this method.
2. Add the 'event' parameter as a second parameter on the `ty` method, since you are binding the button to this method.

This will leave you with:

```
    def metho(self): # this line changed
        self.bnt1 = Button(self.frame1,bg='orange',text='print',height=2,width=7)
        self.bnt1.grid(row=0,column=1)
        self.bnt1.bind("<Enter>",self.ty)

    def ty(self, event): # this line changed
        print("hello")
```

See the docs for more:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.html#bindings-and-events

Answer (score -1):

Here is a corrected code;

```
from tkinter import *
gui = Tk()
gui.geometry("500x500")
gui.configure(bg='orange')
class main:
    def __init__(self,master):
        self.master=master
        self.frame1= Frame(self.master,bg='orange')
        self.frame1.pack(side=TOP)
        self.metho()
    def metho(self):
        self.bnt1 = Button(self.frame1,bg='orange',text='print',height=2,width=7)
        self.bnt1.grid(row=0,column=1)
        self.bnt1.bind("<Enter>",self.ty)

    def ty(self):
        print("hello")

i = main(gui)
gui.mainloop()
```

Comment: How does this address `missing 1 required positional argument`?